# Appending a javascript variable to an html textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I know this has to be be doable, does anyone know how and if you can do it?

Comment: Are you trying to insert the value into the textarea after the existing content?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

or you can do it this way:

```
var myVar = 'sup fresh our turn baby!';
var myTextArea = document.getElementById('myArea');
myTextArea.innerHTML += myVar;
```

Comment: woot woot? then someone might call me a nerd :/

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
var textArea = document.getElementById("mytextarea"); // assuming there is a textarea with id = mytextarea
var textToAppend = document.createTextNode("Hello, World!");
textArea.appendChild(textToAppend);
```

**EDIT:** or, as Pointy suggested, the last two lines can be replaced by:

```
textArea.value += "Hello, World!";
```

Comment: Why not just `textArea.value += textToAppend;` ??

Answer (score 2):

```
function appendText(str) {
var obj=document.getElementById("myTextArea")
var txt=document.createTextNode("append this text")
obj.appendChild(txt)
}
```

Comment: Same question to you as I asked @GreginYEG: why not just append to the "value" attribute of the `<textarea>` ??  Why go to the expense of creating a node (**slow** in IE)?

Answer (score 1):

Gee whiz guys:

```
document.getElementById('whatever').value += someJavascriptString;
```